# Getting fewer results than expected with WHERE IN clause

Tags: mysql

I'm trying this query:

```
SELECT log_veh_id,
    MONTH( log_fecha_tiempo ) AS mes,
    YEAR(log_fecha_tiempo ) AS anio,
    SUM( log_total ) AS suma
    FROM  `dat_fuel_log`
        WHERE log_veh_id IN ('1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24')
GROUP BY MONTH( log_fecha_tiempo ) , YEAR( log_fecha_tiempo ) 
ORDER BY log_fecha_tiempo DESC
```

And I only get a few results:

```
+------------+------+------+--------+
| log_veh_id | mes  | anio | suma   |
+------------+------+------+--------+
|          1 |    9 | 2017 |  85.00 |
|          1 |    8 | 2017 | 146.32 |
|          1 |    7 | 2017 | 187.26 |
|          1 |    6 | 2017 | 257.81 |
|          1 |    5 | 2017 | 263.65 |
|          1 |    4 | 2017 | 152.73 |
|          1 |    3 | 2017 | 193.28 |
|          1 |    2 | 2017 | 222.33 |
|          1 |    1 | 2017 | 114.02 |
+------------+------+------+--------+
```

There are many more log_veh_id = 1 and other IDs (log_veh_id) that fullfil the WHERE IN clause, not just 1's.

Considering that all log_veh_id values will actually be in the values (WHERE IN) I would expect to return all the table results as if I remove the WHERE IN clause.

Comment: Get rid of the quotes around the list of IDs.

Comment: It's converting that string to an integer, which just results in the single number `1`.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar Damn quotes I swear I tried without quotes yesterday. I guess I did not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the log_veh_id is an INT you should not  use quote around values in IN  but

```
SELECT log_veh_id,
    MONTH( log_fecha_tiempo ) AS mes,
    YEAR(log_fecha_tiempo ) AS anio,
    SUM( log_total ) AS suma
    FROM  `dat_fuel_log`
        WHERE log_veh_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24)
GROUP BY MONTH( log_fecha_tiempo ) , YEAR( log_fecha_tiempo ) 
ORDER BY log_fecha_tiempo DESC
```

otherwise if is a char  then you should quote each values

```
SELECT log_veh_id,
    MONTH( log_fecha_tiempo ) AS mes,
    YEAR(log_fecha_tiempo ) AS anio,
    SUM( log_total ) AS suma
    FROM  `dat_fuel_log`
        WHERE log_veh_id IN ('1','2','3','4','5','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24')
GROUP BY MONTH( log_fecha_tiempo ) , YEAR( log_fecha_tiempo ) 
ORDER BY log_fecha_tiempo DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is meant the be supplementary to the other answers/comments:

If the ids are all sequential, you could also just use:

```
WHERE log_veh_id BETWEEN 1 AND 24
```

If for some reason you can't convert the comma-delimited list to individual ints, the corresponding function for a string would be:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(log_veh_id, '1,2,3,4,5,...') > 0
```